# Why does typescript not complain about certain undefined variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I have the following example:

```
class Uncle {
  constructor(public name : string) { }

  talk() {
    return "Hello my name is " + name;
  }
}

let p : Uncle = new Uncle("Jo");
console.log(p.talk());
```

For certain variable names, typescript (right now **Version 2.1.4**) will **not** complain that they are not defined in your program (In the method talk, name is being used without this.). `name` is one of those.

If I rename the variable to, say, `firstName`, the compiler complains rightfully...

> error TS2663: Cannot find name 'firstName'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.firstName'?

Same goes for e.g. window, which is apparently assumed to exist.

My question(s) are:

- Which variable names are assumed to exist and why?
- Can that behaviour be changed (e.g. in some linters you can state which variables you expect to be globally available)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it won't complain about `name` is that there's a variable called name in the global namespace.
Open the console in the developer tools and write `name` and press enter and you'll receive: `""`.

More resources:

- [Mdn page on the property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name)
- [Definition in the lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L19420)

All global variables can be used without defining them.

In order to remove all global definitions you can, e.g. in your `tsconfig.json`, set the `"libs"` option to an empty array. This will remove *all* globals.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to turn this off?

Comment: Turn what off?  The variable `name` exists, what would you like the compiler to do?

Comment: not necessarily e.g. when you write code for a node.js application, window and friends wouldn't exist. In such a case it would be nice if the compiler wouldn't assume the existence of those globals.

Comment: Well, I guess that you can play around with the `--lib` compiler option and get to a configuration which doesn't include `name` (or other declarations) here's the [list of libs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib), I haven't tried it and haven't searched in which lib it's included, but in theory it might be done. But that seems like an over kill to me.